# Can java be used to write blogger widgets?

Tags: java, html, widget, blogger

I want to write a widget for Google's Blogger. Those are created in javascript and html, but is it possible to write it in java (java and html maybe) ? Have you done a thing like this before ?

Comment: I sometimes get this backwards, but I think you want [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino), with the server-side running Java. Yes, it is possible, though. There's probably a [Java blogging system](http://roller.apache.org/) out there...

Comment: You can use Java Applet - it's an old item, so not a lot of people use it anymore - but you can embed the jar inside your html. However it requires the user to install java inside their computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters you will have to take care of the **Server** of the blog for you to use Java Widgets.
It may(must) be possible to write Java widgets but it is not advised.
I would suggest you to use ***HTML/JavaScript and PHP*** for the blogger widgets.